# How can I restart a string iterator endlessly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator

This question is somewhat related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271320/reseting-generator-object-in-python), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266180/can-iterators-be-reset-in-python), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747296/python-iterator-reset-iterator) one. Assume I have two generators/iterators of different lengths:

```
>>> s = "abcde"
>>> r = range(0, 16)
```

I now want to repeat iterating over the shorter one until the longer one is exhausted. The standard [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) function terminates once the shorter of the two is exhausted:

```
>>> for c, i in zip(s, r) :
...     print(c, i)
... 
a 0
b 1
c 2
d 3
e 4
```

The best I can come up with is wrapping the string into a generator like so:

```
>>> def endless_s(s) :
...     while True :
...         for c in s :
...             yield c
```

which gives me the desired result of

```
>>> _s = endless_s(s)
>>> for c, i in zip(_s, r) :
...     print(c, i)
... 
a 0
b 1
c 2
d 3
e 4
a 5
b 6
c 7
d 8
e 9
a 10
b 11
c 12
d 13
e 14
a 15
```

Now I wonder: is there a better and more compact way of doing this? Like an endless string join, or some such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

> Make an iterator returning elements from the iterable and saving a
>   copy of each. When the iterable is exhausted, return elements from the
>   saved copy. Repeats indefinitely.

which is able to replace your function entirely:

```
from itertools import cycle as endless_s
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for: `for c, i in zip(itertools.cycle(s), r)`